# background-colors not showing up

Tags: html, css

I can't get the colors to show up in chrome. I've tried switching the order of the files in `<link>` just in case that is the problem. I don't see any reason why the colors are'nt showing up in chrome.

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="headertext">
          <h1> ROBIN HOBB </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="facebookbuttons"></div>
        <div class="fantasy_text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: body is a tag and not a class  so you must refer as body and not as  .body

Comment: he really has a element with a class called "body" right there.

Comment: Whelp, everything is working just fine in Chrome. Both background colors for `.header` and `.body` are working. `.header` is white on white, so you _"can't see"_ it and `.body` has nothing to give it height (i.e. content, padding, etc. ) and that's why you cannot see that background color.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.body` class DIV doesn't have any content. If you put some text into it, you see the blue background:

(and since the browser windows background is white by default, you won't see the white background on your `.header` DIV...)

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="headertext">
          <h1> ROBIN HOBB </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="facebookbuttons"></div>
        <div class="fantasy_text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">Here is some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="headertext">
          <h1> ROBIN HOBB </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="facebookbuttons"></div>
        <div class="fantasy_text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

I assume you are trying to change the entire page background color which needs to be done with a **body { ... }** selector not **.body{ ... }** as in this sample.

However, if the goal is to target the  with a class of body your CSS is correct but there is nothing inside for content so it has a height of 0 by default. Add content like Johannes mentioned and it should work for you.

Comment: :-) true enough ... so I edited my answer to include the 'odd' <div> with a class of body in case that is the goal. Though I probably should have also mentioned that having a div with a  class of body is a bad practice in Symantec HTML ...